# Translate API - different result from the web service

Tags: google-translate

When using the translation API, I get a different translation (and worse) than if I use translate.google.com.

I am working on a project for a client, and the client was dissatisfied with the translation and noticed the difference.

Do these two service use different engines? I read that the API uses nmt-mode now, and that translate.google.com already uses the same engine.

Both set to translate from Norwegian to English.

Any more information that can clear this up?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you using the translation API ?

Comment: Hei,
Calling this from js:

`https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?format=html&model=nmt&source=no&target=en&q=text&key=foobar`

Answer (score 0):

It's almost about 3 years later and the problem still remains!

So I was trying to translate a dataset with the Google Translate API, but in the end it failed to translate some texts to the target language (in my case, Persian/Farsi). So I decided to check them to see if there's a pattern and maybe translate them using the web version of Google Translate.
As I was doing so, I figured that the web version actually could translate some of those untranslated texts, BUT *not all*. When trying to find a reason for such behaviour, I found out that most of them were names and not sentences. But as we know, names can easily be written with the target language characters as the translation. But why the API doesn't transform those names while the web version does? This photo will explain everything perhaps:
[verified translation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcqJs.png)

As can be seen, some translations have a badge indicating that the translation has been verified, while some others don't.

So to recap, my guess is that maybe the API is set to only use verified translations, but as for the web version, even unverified translations are allowed since you can edit or report them.

Answer (score -1):

The result differences between the **translate.google.com** and the **Translation API** calls are considered as an [expected behavior](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-translate-api/9f_tOyn4M00) that can be generated due to maintenance tasks and the logic used by the internal processes; However, the engines used for each service seems to be private information.

Based on this, it is normal to get some variances when using the API. I think you can use the [model parameter](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text#using_the_model_parameter) option as an available workaround in case you want to specify which of the available models to use, as well as take a look on the [Specifying a model](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text#specifying_a_model) official documentation to get detail information about this alternative.

Comment: I have tried both model parameters. The "base" option results in really bad translation in the texts I have been trying.

The nmt is the default according to the documentation. As far as I can read there are no more options.

What is really weird is that while the translate.google.com in my first tests resulted in the best translation (and no variances during testing), the service now gives me the same translation that I got from the API in my first test.

I guess I will have to check out another solution for this client.

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: This variations might occur since Goolgle is always improving their models which can lead some changes in the transcriptions. In case you consider that the translation result is incorrect, I recommend you to use the pencil icon located at [translate.google.com](http://translate.google.com), as well as post your feedback in the [forum](https://translate.google.com/community) site in order to suggest a better translation; In this way, you will help to improve the service accuracy over the time.